# Getting wrong values from dynamically created check box

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic-ui

I am trying to read from a dynamically created checkbox on button click. The problem is that once the checkbox is checked, further uncheck operation are not read properly on submit click.

EDIT: The checkbox is initially created on the selection of a radiobuttonlist by calling `SetSelection` as shown.

The code snippet is shown below, Any idea what could be the possible problem?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
    ..
        GenerateDynamicUI();
    }
    ...
}     


private void GenerateDynamicUI(int selectedItem)
{
    ...
    TableCell cellCheckBox = new TableCell();
    CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();              
    chkBox.Text = "Consider all";
    chkBox.ID = "chkAll";
    cellCheckBox.Controls.Add(chkBox);

    TableRow chkRow = new TableRow();
    chkRow.Cells.Add(cellCheckBox);
    table.Rows.Add(chkRow);
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)table.FindControl("chkAll")).Checked;   

}

private void SetSelection()
{
    int selectedItem = int.Parse(radiobuttonList.SelectedItem.Value);           
    GenerateDynamicUI(selectedItem);
    pnlDynamic.Visible = true;            
}

protected void radiobuttonList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SetSelection();
}
```

Comment: Does this CheckBox already present in your webform code or it will just created on Postback?

Comment: It's created dynamically, in his GenerateDynamicUI method.

Comment: I cant find any issue in this code its giving me correct value of checkbox each time. Can you elaborate your problematic scenario?

Comment: I second that, also is this the entire declaration of the CheckBox and its containing Controls? I'm wondering if the CheckBox is being modified at some stage?

Comment: Please see edited code. I am having a radiobutton list. Based on the selection, I am creating the checkbox dynamically using `SetSelection` method. SCENARIO: When the checkbox is not checked and when I do a submit, isChecked is giving false and when I check it and do submit, it is returning true (as expected). But when I uncheck it again, still it is returning true.

Comment: Are you calling GenerateDynamicUI from Page_Load AND from your RadioButtonList SelectedIndexChanged?

Answer (score 4):

I've recreated your example and it works fine. I can only imagine there's something else in your code responsible for the unexpected behaviour.

Try using the `Page_PreInit` event rather than `Page_Load` to re-create/manipulate your dynamic controls:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create controls here
    GenerateDynamicUI();
}
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

By 'not ready properly' I assume you mean it stays `True` and never returns `False` after the first time you've check it?

Comment: Yes, it stays True and never returns False after the first time I check it.

Comment: +1 for building dynamic controls in PreInit.  That's where they belong

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you declaring

```
bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)table.FindControl("chkAll")).Checked;
```

in the btnSubmit if so it would be reset to false every time the method is called. try declaring it out side. IE:

```
bool isChecked;
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    isChecked = ((CheckBox)table.FindControl("chkAll")).Checked;   

}
```

Comment: This won't matter, it's a local var. Furthermore it's written to each time.